# SQL Server / XML.query() causes massive memory grant

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery, memory-grant

The following (on my systems, tested on SQL Server 2016 and 2019 std) produces a massive memory grant request (3327 MB)

```
declare @wibble xml = '<wibble><wobble>1</wobble></wibble>'

select @wibble.query('//wobble[1]')
```

Is there anything I can do to reduce the grant?

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkezxS8-K

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With a quick look at your xpath expression `//wobble[1]` and the test data you have you are looking for the first `wobble` you can find.

One could even think that your expression is equal to this `(//wobble)[1]` which with your test data gives the same result. Using the parenthesis like that you will get the first `wobble` from the XML document and there will be no memory grant for the query.

So, as you might know using `//wobble[1]` (without the parenthesis) is not the same at all. This query will look at all elements in the document and if there are a `wobble` element in there it will return the first one and concatenate the result with all elements.

For example.

```
<wibble>
  <wobble>1</wobble>
  <wobble>2</wobble>
  <wobble>3</wobble>
  <wibble>
    <nowobblehere>X</nowobblehere>
    <wobble>A</wobble>
    <wobble>B</wobble>
    <wobble>C</wobble>
  </wibble>
</wibble>
```

Using `//wobble[1]` you will get

```
<wobble>1</wobble>
<wobble>A</wobble>
```

Where using `(//wobble)[1]` would only give you `<wobble>1</wobble>`.

If you really need the concatenated result you could shred your nodes and then rebuild them using `for xml path` to get a smaller memory grant. For me it requests 1MB instead of 280MB. Still with a warning of excessive memory grant.

```
select T.X.query('wobble[1]')
from @wibble.nodes('//*[wobble]') as T(X)
for xml path('');
```

`//*[wobble]` gives you all nodes that has a `wobble` node and `wobble[1]` gives you the first `wobble` in that node.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks Mikael and Rob

Answer (score 3):

Consider hinting the query with MAX_GRANT_PERCENT:-

```
DECLARE @wibble XML = '<wibble><wobble>1</wobble></wibble>';

SELECT @wibble.query('//wobble[1]')
OPTION (MAX_GRANT_PERCENT = 0);
```

Documented here:- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3107401